Выражение «теперь уже» — это семантический плеоназм?
Выражение «теперь уже» — это семантический плеоназм?
Теперь, значения:


в тот отрезок времени, к которому относится настоящий, данный момент (часто употребляется при сопоставлении настоящего и предшествующего времени) ◆ Теперь мы не ищем работу, работа находит нас.
при изменившихся обстоятельствах, при создавшихся условиях (употребляется для указания на обусловленность одного действия другим, предшествующим) ◆ Теперь ему придётся делать более тщательные проверки.
употребляется для указания на действие, событие и т. п., которое является или должно быть следующим по порядку ◆ А теперь перейдём к вопросам.


Уже, значения:


употребляется при указании на окончательное совершение, наступление, выполнение чего-либо ◆ Работа уже сделана.
употребляется при указании на смену места, времени, обстоятельств действия ◆ Я уже не директор.
к настоящему времени, на данный момент ◆ Он давно уже занимается спортом.


Видно, что в 2-х случаях (из 3-х) значения совпадают. Сл-но, выражение «теперь уже» — это семантический плеоназм?
Примеры:

Теперь уже мы не ищем работу, работа находит нас.
Он давно теперь уже занимается спортом.
Теперь уже ему придётся делать более тщательные проверки.
Я теперь уже не директор.


Аналогичный вопрос к выражению «уже теперь».

Не плеоназм.
Думаю, в большей части из приведённых Вами примеров УЖЕ не наречие, а частица, усиливающая слово ТЕПЕРЬ.
См.:
Большой универсальный словарь русского языка:

УЖЕ 2, част.
<…>
2.0. Употр. для подчёркивания, выделения какого-л. слова или словосочетания.
□ Уже в самом этом слове есть что-то неприятное.

В предложении же:
Я теперь уже не директор.
— частица уже подчёркивает скорее не теперь, а слова не директор.

Рассмотрим вне контекста три словосочетания: «давно уже» (>14 000 вхождений в НКРЯ), «теперь уже» (>10 000), «скоро уже» (>400). Если принять для «уже» значение «к настоящему времени, на данный момент», то два первых сочетания – плеоназмы, а третье – абсурд.
Скоро уже ничего нельзя было различить, и каждый орудовал в свою голову. [Д. Н. Мамин-Сибиряк. Хлеб (1895)]
Но в этом примере (из НКРЯ) ничего абсурдного нет, поскольку «уже» сочетается здесь не со «скоро», «теперь», «давно», а с «ничего нельзя было различить». Т.е. «уже» определяет не время совершения действия, а его полноту – целостность –  безупречность – безусловность – окончательный характер.
Кроме того, «уже» может указывать на факт: достижения предела (все / хватит / достаточно / больше нет сомнений / нет и не будет никаких исключений), прохождения точки невозврата, наступления события (изменения статуса / состояния), зачастую в форме противопоставления: «уже» не так, а иначе (не то, а иное / не туда, а обратно / не прямо, а зигзагом)...
Знала, что теперь уже конец всем самообманам. [Марк Криницкий. Маскарад чувства (1915)]
Сына Митю — теперь уже врача — я видела редко. [И. Грекова. Перелом (1987)]
В двух последних примерах (из НКРЯ) нельзя опустить слово «уже» без ущерба для понимания смысла фразы. А это важнейший признак отсутствия плеоназма и даже тени его.
Пары слов, области значений которых частично пересекаются – никакая не редкость. Правильно выстроенный контекст (или одна только фраза) переводит значения таких слов в непересекающиеся области.
Впрочем, при наличии желания, путем сокращения контекста можно достичь и противоположного результата, в чем легко убедиться, разбирая примеры из вопроса.
Эти примеры можно немного «исковеркать», чтобы снизить степень их «плеоназменности»:
1.Теперь уже не мы ищем работу, - работа (ищет и) находит нас.
2. Теперь уже и он (сам) занимается спортом.
3.Теперь уже ему (самому, а не кому то другому) придётся делать более тщательные проверки.
4.Я теперь уже не директор, а депутат ЗС.

Позовите Васю.

Он ушел.
Он уже ушел.
Он теперь уже ушел.

Ну тут различия в акцентах, не сказал бы что есть строгие различия в смыслах.
Так что можно и плеоназмом называть, коли охота.

Экспериментально-дискуссионный ответ

Начну с принципа, который называется "бритва Оккама."
Научно-философское правило, известное как бритва Оккама, 
названо по имени монаха-францисканца Уильяма из Оккама — 
деревни в графстве Суррей в Южной Англии. Он жил в XIII 
веке, занимался теологией, к которой тогда, по сути, 
сводилась научная мысль, и активно практиковал идею 
упрощения в подходе к философии. В своих трудах он 
неоднократно призывал по возможности всегда выбирать 
более простые объяснения для чего бы то ни было.



Другими словами, объяснять тему надо как можно проще.

Я правлю предложения по слуху: убираю избыточность, если она есть, и меняю порядок слов, если нужно:

(1) Теперь уже не мы ищем работу, а работа находит нас.
(2) Он давно уже / занимается спортом.
(3) Теперь ему уже придётся делать / более тщательные проверки.
(4) Теперь я уже / не директор.
Сравниваю ответы и вижу, что разница есть. У меня избыточность получилась только во втором предложении. Там давно и теперь противоречат друг другу.

Как я это делаю, будучи носителем языка? Вообще-то интуитивно, но выбор могу объяснить.

Это интонационный анализ и определение порядка слов по семантике и грамматике. Здесь уже интереснее: второе наречие может быть лишним по смыслу, а может корректировать или дополнять смысл других слов.

Я определяю возможность сужения смысла сказанного при наличии временного наречия "уже" ПО ВРЕМЕНИ, ПО ОБСТОЯТЕЛЬСТВАМ, ПО СИТУАЦИИ. И тогда можно сделать вывод, что в большинстве случаев ПЛЕОНАЗМА НЕТ. Также можно сравнить с английским переводом: already и now. Например: I'm already a director now.

В чем тут сужение/коррекция смысла? ВРЕМЕННОЕ ПРОСТРАНСТВО теперь — сейчас корректируется по обстоятельствам: тогда был директор, а сейчас УЖЕ нет. Не стоит забывать, что это прежде всего наречие времени.

При решении я предполагаю  историческую связь между словами уже и узкий.

Доказать это по этимологии сложно, но сложно и опровергнуть.
В этих словах можно "почувствовать"  и-е. корень u-, который как бы "стягивает" временное или другое пространство, а ЖЕ — это усилительная частица.
Кстати, не так давно на форуме обсуждали образную природу и-е. корней.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (о переходе наречия УЖЕ в частицу)

Как узнать, что такой переход состоялся? Довольно сложно. В словаре ясно указано:
УЖЕ. I. нареч. **Случилось наступило, совершилось** 
(какое-л. действие, состояние). У. наступила ночь. У. 
кто-л. приехал. У. поправился. У. начался урок. У. было 
поздно. // **Изменилось (какое-л. обстоятельство, условие 
и т.п.)**. Встретились у. в саду. Работа пошла у. легче. 
Глядеть у. дружелюбно.



Другими словами, при наличии дополнительной характеристики у нас по-прежнему наречие.

А когда же происходит переход? При усилении и подчеркивании значимости какого-либо ОБСТОЯТЕЛЬСТВА (времени, количества и т.д.).
II. частица. 1. Усиливает значимость сообщаемого о 
продолжительности какого-л. отрезка времени, подчёркивает 
его длительность. Не виделись у. несколько лет. 2. 
Усиливает значимость сообщаемого о количестве чего-л., 
подчёркивает значительность сообщаемого. Пить у. третий 
стакан. 3. Усиливает значимость слов и словосочетаний, с 
которыми связано по смыслу. У. давно уехал кто-л. У. по 
глазам видно всё. У. все листья облетели с деревьев.


А кто решает, что надо подчеркнуть значимость и какими средствами это можно сделать? Вот это уже вопрос.


Вот простейший пример: Уже наступила осень. Здесь уже — наречие со значением: случилось, наступило, совершилось (какое-л. действие, состояние).
Осень наступила уже по всем приметам.  А здесь что, наречие или частица? Вроде бы наречие. Как же мне подчеркнуть значимость?

Можно предположить, что усиление есть в таком предложении: Уже все листья облетели с деревьев.

Количество выражено, а уже подчеркивает это количество.  Но все-таки сомнения остаются.
